# javascript regex to match a char if not inside a markdown code block

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to figure out how to match all char `'` that are not between a markdown code block. Using VSCode extension [regreplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DomiR.regreplace)

VSCode seems to use Javascript regex.

ex:

````
match this one '

```
don't match this
```

match this as well '

```
not this one '
```

yes to this one '

`not this ' one`
````

the goal being to replace the matching ones with `’` char

At the moment I have this regex:

```
(?:(?!`[.\n]*?'))(')[.\n]*?(?!`)
```

which match all the `'` even those in a code block.

Comment: depending on regex engine it can be easier or not, is it PCRE?

Comment: I'm trying to use regreplace plugin for VSCode, I don't know which regex engine vscode uses :-/

Comment: You won't be able to do this in VSCode, use SublimeText3 with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/mzkWUa/1/).

Comment: It's not a one time task, I'm writing my blog with vscode and I wanted some automation for typography :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as a last resort.
It finds a `'` that precedes any even set of code delimiters `
which means it's outside, not inside.

I say as a last resort because this is an inefficient way to do it.
But, it shouldn't be too bad if the amount of blocks is not that great.

Find:

```
'(?=[^`]*(?:`[^`]*`[^`]*)*$)
```

Replace: `’`

Example:  https://regex101.com/r/gdkvdq/1

Readable version:

```
 ' 
 (?=
      [^`]* 
      (?:
           ` [^`]* ` 
           [^`]* 
      )*
      $ 
 )
```

Comment: Until VSCode uses ECMA 2018 (with lookbehind support) I think I have no choice, thanks!